# WPF - HorizontalAlignment="Right" does nothing

Tags: wpf, xaml

I am trying to make a custom title bar for my window. I have a grid with buttons, that are all the same size, but they refuse to align right. Here is my XAML code:

```xml
<Window x:Class="EditorZero.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:EditorZero"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="EditorZero" Height="768" Width="1200" WindowStartupLocation="CenterScreen" WindowStyle="None" AllowsTransparency="True" ResizeMode="CanResize">
    <Border BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="2px">
        <Grid>
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="36"></RowDefinition>
                <RowDefinition Height="*"></RowDefinition>
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <Canvas Grid.Row="0" Background="#343434">
                <Grid Width="150px" Height="36px" HorizontalAlignment="Right">
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="50px"></ColumnDefinition>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="50px"></ColumnDefinition>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="50px"></ColumnDefinition>
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <Button Grid.Column="0">X</Button>
                    <Button Grid.Column="1">[]</Button>
                    <Button Grid.Column="2">-</Button>
                </Grid>
            </Canvas>
            <Canvas Grid.Row="1" Background="#232323"></Canvas>
        </Grid>
    </Border>
</Window>
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove the `Canvas`:

```
<Border BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="2px">
    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="36"></RowDefinition>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"></RowDefinition>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Grid Width="150px" Height="36px" Background="#343434" HorizontalAlignment="Right">
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="50px"></ColumnDefinition>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="50px"></ColumnDefinition>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="50px"></ColumnDefinition>
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <Button Grid.Column="0">X</Button>
            <Button Grid.Column="1">[]</Button>
            <Button Grid.Column="2">-</Button>
        </Grid>
        <Canvas Grid.Row="1" Background="#232323"></Canvas>
    </Grid>
</Border>
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of wrapping inside a canvas, wrap it inside a grid.

I see that you have set a background to the canvas and that is why you are using it. So, apply the background to another Grid. Place your grid of interest inside that as shown below.

```
 <Grid>
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="36"></RowDefinition>
                <RowDefinition Height="*"></RowDefinition>
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <Grid Grid.Row="0" Background="#343434">
            <Grid Width="150px" Height="36px" HorizontalAlignment="Right">
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="50px"></ColumnDefinition>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="50px"></ColumnDefinition>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="50px"></ColumnDefinition>
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <Button Grid.Column="0">X</Button>
                    <Button Grid.Column="1">[]</Button>
                    <Button Grid.Column="2">-</Button>
                </Grid>
            </Grid>
            <Canvas Grid.Row="1" Background="#232323"></Canvas>
        </Grid>
```